# Get the control that caused the binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

On WPF, I have a window with one or more textboxes bound to the same property.

On my `Set()` function, I would like to be able to know which control caused the binding.

I would like to know from which control this binding is provokate in order to force the focus to stay in this control if the validation is false.

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: Your viewmodel should not know about any view elements like textboxes. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I edit my post : I would like to know from which control this binding is provokate in order to force the focus to stay in this control if the validation is false.

Answer (score 1):

Can you name each textbox in xaml then set an event on the textbox to check when it has changed, like so?

```
<TextBox Mame="textBox1" TextChanged="OnTextChanged"/>
```

This way you'll get an event call and you can do whatever you want in that event call in the code behind, like so.

```
    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox= sender as TextBox;
        if(textbox.Name=="textBox1")
            //Do Something

    }
```

Comment: I would like to know from which control this binding is provokate in order to force the focus to stay in this control if the validation is false.

Comment: the above code should tell you which control was changed during binding, you just need to add the rest of the textboxes to your xaml and your code behind.  The `if` statement will trigger if that control was affected by the binding.  From there you can decide what to do with that control.